How do I find the length of one word in Python and output it?
I can not get it to output the answer of the length of the word. and I'm really stuck.
I tried this:
def wordlength():
   word = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"
   len(word)
wordlength()

It hasn't outputted anything, so if anyone has any idea what's over I would be grateful.
I am trying to get it to output the right length, but there has been no output. Someone mentioned something about a count controlled loop, but I don't know how to use it in this context.

len(word) prints 34

@Wonka It doesn't print anything. It merely calculates the length and throws away the result, which is the OPs problem.

Hi @Ellie, source of your confusion might be in you not knowing difference between python interactive and script mode. You are obviously just beginning so most likely all your code until now was executed in interactive mode. That's the one when you open up a terminal with python prompt. In this mode returned values are automagically captured and printed in that terminal. But if you write code in a separate file and then run it as, a script, there's no terminal that captures and prints that output for you, you have tell your script to actually show value returned by len(), print(len(word))

The other quesion is: what do you want your function to do? 1) Return word length? Or maybe 2) print word length? If 1 - your function lacks return len(word), if 2 - your function lacks print(len(word)) :)

As the code you post above, your function did not return anything. You should return the length:
def wordlength():
    word = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"
    return len(word)

print(wordlength())

